# How to bridge Spring Application Context events to an other context

Tags: java, spring, events

I have a Spring web application with two contexts: one (`applicationContext`) built by `ContextLoaderListener` and a second (`webContext`) built by `DispatcherServlet`.

Within the `applicationContext` is a bean (`org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher`) that fires spring context events.

But the receiver for the event is defined in the `webContext`. And that receiver did not get the event. (If put the receiver for test purpose in the `applicationContext` then it get the event, but I can not do this, because I need the `webContext`s for its functionality.)

So my question is, how to bridges the events from the `applicationContext` to `webContext`?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: I'm guessing by design Spring doesn't allow you to do this. Otherwise wouldn't it be very confusing if you're debugging which class handled the event? Now instead of looking within one container, you have to look all

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, solved mine by moving the beans creating the event to web-context. However you can solve your problem by manually wiring your event listener, something like this (this code is not compiled therefore it is untested):

```
@Component    
public class BeanInWebContext implements ApplicationListener<SomeEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext webContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerAsListener() {
        // get parent context
        AbstractApplicationContext appContext = (AbstractApplicationContext) webContext.getParent();
        // register self as a listener, this method is in AbstractApplicationContext
        appContext.addApplicationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SomeEvent event) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the actual answer is that you may want to configure your app differently (so that you only have one context)
I think in your web.xml you need to do something like this :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>               
            classpath:/META-INF/applicationSpringConfig.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

But to answer the deeper question. Someone else points out that you can use includes in your spring file (indeed in the above you can have more than one springconfig specified in your dispatcher servlet).
But when you include other context files you do not share instances of beans, only definitions.

Modularising Spring applications has been the only real downside of spring in comparison with EJB etc. That led spring into using OSGi.
And the answer to your underlying question of how to share spring context, officially you share spring bean instances between contexts using OSGi (spring dm)

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the event publisher to the web context file, where it should have visibility over the whole application context. A similar issue occurs when [configuring method security in the parent application context](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context). The parent application context (loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`) isn't aware of the child (web) context.

You can also use a single application context for the entire application if you don't really need the parent-child relationship between the two. Often it just gets in the way and it is easier if all beans were defined in the same space.

Comment: This can't be the solution, because the question is about how to handle the two contexts. (I can not move the security stuff in the web context, because I explicite use it in the application (it is a application with ACLs)).

Comment: Do you actually need two separate application contexts? It sounds like a situation where it might be simpler just to have one.

Comment: this sounds much better. I will check why I used two context, and look if I can merge them.

Comment: Two contexts is often the default setup. As an alternative, you can just use the `DispatcherServlet` context use import statements to add the other context files.

Comment: Two contexts are needed (in my case), because the parent context is needed for some filters (Spring Security's DelegatingFilterProxy,...) @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not

Answer (score 3):

As stated in documentation for the spring framework the simple ApplicationEvent mechanism is only designed to be used within the same application context, I am not aware that it is possible to propagate events to child contexts.

If you need a more advanced solution you might look into using a more enhanced solution like Java Message Service or Spring Integration.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events

Answer (score 0):

We can use the import tag to import/bridge the 2 different contexts created in a way the visibility of the events/beans are available and shared.

```
<import resource="applicationContext_name.xml"/>
```

In this import the context xml which is configured to be created from ContextLoaderListener in the context xml of the DispatcherServlet.