# Can I define beans inside dispatcher-servlet

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

In my web.xml I have removed `contextConfigLocation` and instead of pointing to `application context` I defined my beans in my dispatcher-servlet. Is that allowed or Spring looks for contextConfigLocation for sure?

```
<!--context-param>        //This part is commented. Is this allowed?
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener-->
```

By beans inside dispatcher servlet...

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Xe"
        p:username="hibernate"
        p:password="hibernate"></bean>
```

Comment: Short answer - yes you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but they will be visible in web context only. Look at this answer [Spring can't see beans between servlet-context and contextConfigLocation beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531428/spring-cant-see-beans-between-servlet-context-and-contextconfiglocation-beans)

Quote from the Spring Framework API (at the moment of writing 3.2.2) for the [WebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html):

> Like generic application contexts, web application contexts are
>   hierarchical. **There is a single root context per application, while
>   each servlet in the application (including a dispatcher servlet in the
>   MVC framework) has its own child context**.

Also here: [Context hierarchies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-ctx-hierarchies):

> For example, if you are developing a Spring MVC web application you
>   will typically have a **root WebApplicationContext loaded via Spring's
>   ContextLoaderListener** and a **child WebApplicationContext loaded via
>   Spring's DispatcherServlet**. This results in a parent-child context
>   hierarchy where shared components and infrastructure configuration are
>   declared in the root context and consumed in the child context by
>   web-specific components.

And here: [17.2 The DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

> ApplicationContext instances in Spring can be scoped. In the Web MVC
>   framework, **each DispatcherServlet has its own WebApplicationContext,
>   which inherits all the beans already defined in the root
>   WebApplicationContext**. These inherited beans can be overridden in the
>   servlet-specific scope, and you can define new scope-specific beans
>   local to a given Servlet instance.

Not the last sentence:

> you can define new scope-specific beans local to a given Servlet instance