# Spring Security + MVC : Questions around context definition & bean scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to understand the reccommended way for defining Spring Security in Spring-MVC applications, where the bean definitions is split across multiple parent/child contexts.

For example, my current app's `web.xml` looks as follows, (which I understand to be fairly standard)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, I have a standard `ContextLoaderListener` defined at `/`, which loads my global configs - `applicationContext.xml` and `securityContext.xml`.
I also define the spring mvc `DispatcherServlet` at `/app/`, which loads it's own beans from `spring-mvc-servlet.xml`.

As I understand it, config defined in `spring-mvc-servlet.xml` is not visible to config defined in either of the top-level context files.

Where then is the best place to define app-level security concepts?  For example, I'd like to add the following filter.

```
<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>
```

This is so that requests to `/app/oauth/token` pass through this filter, and get basic authentication processed.

Because this pertains directly to a concern of the Spring-MVC app, I initially defined it in `spring-mvc-context.xml` (which is why the `app` is excluded from the url).

However, this means it's not visible to the security config defined in `securityContext.xml`, so it's ignored.

So, I move it up to `securityContext.xml`, but in doing so, also must move all the dependencies.
I quickly end up moving everything up to `applicationContext.xml`, which leaves the `spring-mvc-context.xml` almost empty.

Is this common?  What is the reccomended split between what is defined in top-level contexts, and what gets defined in child contexts?

Given that spring-mvc defines a series of controllers, which I want to mark as `@Secured`, how will these be processed if the controller is not visible to the security context?

Do I need to move my `<mvc:annotation-driven />` from the `servlet.xml` to the global `applicationContext.xml`?
Do I need additional configuration within the `spring-mvc-servlet.xml` to tell it to participate in Spring security?

I've read the [documentation on Spring-MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet), but there's very few specifics on how to configure this.
Additionally, the [Spring OAuth examples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) seem to define everything within a single config file, which doesn't seem very real-world, and seems to contradict other examples I've read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: the beans defined within `applicationContext.xml` (`ContextLoaderListener`) can not access the one defined in `spring-mvc-servlet.xml` (`DispatcherServlet`) but not the other way around.

You asked:

---

> Given that spring-mvc defines a series of controllers, which I want to mark as @Secured, how will these be processed if the controller is not visible to the security context?

So this works without problems, because the controllers must be defined in the `spring-mvc-servlet.xml`, so they "see" the Spring Security stuff defined in `applicationContext.xml`

---

> Do I need to move my  from the servlet.xml to the global applicationContext.xml?

No

---

> Do I need additional configuration within the spring-mvc-servlet.xml to tell it to participate in Spring security?

No

---

> ... which leaves the spring-mvc-context.xml almost empty. Is this common?

The `spring-mvc-context.xml` should contain every thing that is related to Web Stuff (except secrutiy). So the common parts of the `spring-mvc-context.xml` are component scan for `@Controller`, some Interceptors (`mvc:interceptors`), `mvc:resources`, `mvc:default-servlet-handler`, `mvc:view-controller`, `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, `CookieLocaleResolver`, `.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`...

*BTW: If you use component scan, then you need two of them, one at `applicationContext.xml` to scan for `@Service` `@Repository` and `@Component` (But not `@Controller`) and a second in  `spring-mvc-context.xml` that only scan for `@Controller`!*

---

@See also this question: [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not) It discuss the theme from an other point of view.