# What hierarchy should I setup in Spring configuration files?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-security

I am currently refactoring our Spring configuration files in our webapps. Now, I have grouped them by topic:

```
/WEB-INF/spring
  ./mvc/servlet-context.xml
  ./cache.xml
  ./root-context.xml
  ./security.xml
```

`./*.xml` are loaded by `ContextLoaderListener` which is the Spring root context and all stuff in `./mvc/*.xml` are loaded by the subcontext of the DispatcherServlet.

I know if I do load the `security.xml` by the dispatcher context all beans won't be visible to the parent context.

Now, should a loader hierarchy look like? What should be loaded by root and what by the sub context?

Comment: I hope this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not  and its answer helps you a bit

Comment: Partially, yes. I'd like to hear other options too.