# FailoverTransport instantiated multiple times

Tags: spring, jms, websphere, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm using spring-jms version 3.0.5 and activeMQ version 4.5.2. When deployed to Tomcat, everything seems to work properly. When deployed to WebSphere, it appears that four separate failover transports are being insantiated, and my MessageListener implementation receives the same message four times for every message that gets published to my topic.

Here's my config:

```
<bean id="activeMQConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
       <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://(tcp://server.com:12345,tcp://server2.com:12345)?randomize=false/>
</bean>

<bean id="topic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="TOPIC.ONE" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.sprinframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="topic" />
</bean>

<bean name="topicListener" class="com.foo.TopicListener" />

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" cache="auto" destination-type="topic">
    <jms:listener destination="topic" ref="topicListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Here's my message listener:

```
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TopicListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        log(msg);
    }

}
```

And here's what I see in my logs (only on WebSphere)

```
11:59:59,764 () INFO (Thread-50) (DefaultLifecycleProcessor) Starting beans in phase 214783647
12:00:00,140 () INFO (ActiveMQ Task) (FailoverTransport) Successfully connected to tcp://server.com:12345
12:00:00,253 () INFO (ActiveMQ Task) (FailoverTransport) Successfully connected to tcp://server.com:12345
12:00:00,342 () INFO (ActiveMQ Task) (FailoverTransport) Successfully connected to tcp://server.com:12345
12:00:00,423 () INFO (ActiveMQ Task) (FailoverTransport) Successfully connected to tcp://server.com:12345
12:00:00,492 () INFO (Thread-50) (ContextLoader) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 100239 ms
```

And then once I publish to the topic, I see:

```
12:01:00,250 () INFO (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1) (TopicListener) logging message
12:01:00,251 () INFO (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#3-1) (TopicListener) logging message
12:01:00,251 () INFO (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#2-1) (TopicListener) logging message
12:01:00,275 () INFO (org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1-1) (TopicListener) logging message
```

I've seen some indication that this sort of behavior might be expected if I'd set `concurrentConsumers > 1`, but as far as I can tell, I haven't. How can I make sure I'm only receiving these messages once?

UPDATE:

With debug logging on, I also see:

```
2012-10-28 12:00:00,000 () DEBUG (Thread-50) (DefaultLifecycleProcessor) Starting bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0' of type [class org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
2012-10-28 12:00:00,011 () DEBUG (Thread-50) (DefaultLifecycleProcessor) Starting bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1' of type [class org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
2012-10-28 12:00:00,021 () DEBUG (Thread-50) (DefaultLifecycleProcessor) Starting bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#2' of type [class org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
2012-10-28 12:00:00,029 () DEBUG (Thread-50) (DefaultLifecycleProcessor) Starting bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#3' of type [class org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer]
```

Why would Spring create four of these beans?

Comment: Do you have clustering enabled in websphere?

Comment: Yes -- the cluster this runs in has two servers.

Comment: Do you think this is because of multiple instances of the application being created in the cluster and since the beans are application context specific and each instance in the cluster has different application context, there are as many of the TopicListners as the number of instances in the cluster?

Comment: I don't think so for a few reasons. 1) I have two instances, but four listeners. 2) The logs are separate for each instance, and I see this behavior in both logs. I could be convinced otherwise, though.

Comment: How does your application create the Spring application context? (The logs suggest that you are not using ContextLoaderListener for that.)

Comment: It uses the ContextLoaderListener and a DispatcherServlet -- more or less the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not