# Custom UserDetailsService not executing correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, controller, spring-security

I'm trying to configure Spring Security but I have an extrange problem with my custom UserDetailsService. Everytime I try to login in I'm redirected to my failure page. This is the code of the service:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        logger.info("This is printed");

        UserDetails userDetails = userService.findOne(username);

        logger.info("This isn't printed");

        if (userDetails == null) {
            logger.info("This isn't printed");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username "
                    + username);
        }

        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

As you can see in the code, some of the loggers are never printed and that is a little weird...

This are my User model, its repository and its service classes:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    // more code


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findOne(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Spring Security filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- This is used to inject webroot property (used by persistence.xml) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.leakedbits.twicker.listener.WebAppPropertiesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/init2" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login/failure"
            default-target-url="/" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />

        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout/success"
            logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <!-- This line must to be here because for some random reason the implementation 
        wasn't found without it -->
    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
        class="com.leakedbits.twicker.service.security.CustomUserDetailsService" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Finally, the code that I run previously to add a test user:

```
User user = new User();
user.setPassword("7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b"); // 123456
user.setUsername("davidmogar");
Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
user.setGrantedAuthorities(grantedAuthorities);
userService.save(user);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

For an unknown reason, userService is null so is not being autowired. I'm not sure which could be the problem. This service is working well inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Add `autowire="byType"` to the xlm definition of the userDetailsService bean

And remove the service annotation from the class, else you would have two instances of it.

Comment: I have no userDetailsService bean definition. About the Service annotation, I used it to load the service but it didn't work for an unknown reason and I had to add the bean deffinition. When I remove the bean declaration I get this error: "No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' is defined" How could I solve this?

Comment: It is in your security. XML !

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking... xD I added autowyre="byType" because "type" is not recognized. Anyway, doesn't work. Is it possible to use only Service annotation?

Comment: Try to create a constructor that take the user service as an parameter. Than add @Auto wire to this constructor, remove all other annotations. In the XML use auto wire,="constructor"

Comment: I've done all except "add @Autowire to this constructor" because I don't know what you mean. Anyway, doesn't work. I get this error: No matching bean of type [com.leakedbits.twicker.repository.service.UserService]

Comment: Ok, I've added <context:component-scan base-package="com.leakedbits.twicker" /> to root-context.xml and all is working now. Could you help me to understand the problem?

Comment: If you use @Service etc, you need to enable component scanning, otherwise the bean will not be located and instantiated by Spring. Think of it as a shortcut alternative to using a <bean /> definition.

Comment: @David Moreno Garcia: Jukka's explanation is right. Normaly a bean that is found by component scan is cerated by its none argumemt constructor; if you want it to use an other constructor the place the `@Autowire` annotation at this constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that line was already in my servlet-context.xml which is referenced by web.xml. Now I have one there and one in root-context.xml.

Comment: First: read this question, skaffman's answer and my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not   (you should know that spring security is based on an servlet-filter and therefore need its beans define in the application-context (that's why it start working after you add the 2. Component scann)). --- second: configure your two component scans so that every bean class is found only by one of the 2 scanns.