# All Spring Framework beans get duplicated, becase of doubled context (servlet+ContextLoaderListener)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

- If I create spring context **by dispatcher servlet**, I got an error in`DelegatingFilterProxy` filter:

  ```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
  ```
- If I create spring context **by `ContextLoaderListener`** I just have `404` error beacuse of **no servlet**
- If I create spring context **by both servlet & listener** I have duplicated context, so all beans are duplicated, including controllers with request mappings, double-executing `@Scheduled` methods etc.

**How to create advanced spring application (including lot of filters etc.) without duplicating context?**

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

        <display-name>MyWebApplication</display-name>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <listener>
                <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
             </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                        /WEB-INF/spring.xml
                </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- UTF-8 -->
        <filter>
             <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
             <filter-class>
                 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
             </filter-class>
             <init-param>
                 <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                 <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
             </init-param>
             <init-param>
             <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
             </init-param>
         </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

         <!-- Spring Security -->
        <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You will need to post your configurations and web.xml/WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: use two distinct xml files, one for spring context (all but mvc part), one for the dispatcher servlet (mvc part)

Comment: @RC. Do not helps. Removed context-param, so litener starting from empty (no-beans) applicationContext.xml and deployment error is: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`

Comment: I guess you don't need to pass it as `init-param` , just defined `contextConfigLocation`

Comment: see [this sample web](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml), one xml for mvc stuff, and 2 for spring stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use spring related servlet filters and also use mvc controllers, then you need both:

- ContextLoaderListener AND
- DispatcherServlet-spring-configuration

(See [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not))

Both create their own servlet context.
The ContextLoaderListener create the **parent-context** (sometimes called the inner-context). And the DispatcherServlet create a **child-context** (of the parent context) (sometimes called the outer-context).
The beans of the child-context can access the beans of the parent-context, but not the other way around.

In a not too simple web application you need both contexts, because the there are many servlet filters that requires an already created spring context. On the other hand, all the controller stuff needs a ServletContext, and this is only created by the Dispatcher Servlet.

Another point is, that you should not have every bean created twice (sometimes this is no problem, other times it is). So you need to have two spring configurations, one for the inner context, one for the other context. And you need to decide for every bean whether it belongs to the inner or to the outer context.

The rule of thumb is: put every thing in the inner context, except that stuff that requires a Servlet context or is heavily tied to the Web-frontend, like MVC-Controllers, Tiles configuration, ....

Comment: Thanks, already tried to separate but the key information I was lack was the **ContextLoaderListener is parent**. Moving everything to applicationContext.xml solved problem - now I can move some beans to web context for cleanup. **Note that only separating XMLs will not help if you still have all your beans in webspring context**

Comment: Good explaination Ralph. Just to add, keep business layer into parent-context and delegate web-fronted to outer-context(DispathcerServlet Context).