# spring 4.2 application event is firing twice with Spring MVC , why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with [Spring 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT events](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) , to some reason that I haven't figured out yet,the listener is firing twice after publishing any events whether extending from ApplicationEvent or any arbitrary event, however everything works as expected while running test-cases, now wondering what is going on with annotation-driven events in Spring MVC context

**Event publishing Interface**

```
public interface ListingRegistrationService {
    public void registerListing(ListingResource listing);

}

@Component
class ListingRegistrationServiceImpl implements ListingRegistrationService{

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Autowired
    public ListingRegistrationServiceImpl(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerListing(ListingResource listing) {
       //process
        publisher.publishEvent(new ListingCreatedEvent(listing));
        System.out.println("Event above...");
    }

}
```

**Event Listener**

```
@EventListener
    @Async
    public void sendMailForSuggestedListing(Supplier<ListingResource> listingCreatedEvent)  {
        System.out.println("Event fired...");
    }
```

**end-point/entry point**

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> registerListing(@RequestBody @Valid ListingResource listing,BindingResult result) throws URISyntaxException {
       ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> response = null;
       listingService.registerListing(listing); //  publish the event
       response = ResponseEntity.created(new URI(""));
         return response;
            }
```

Result :
Event fired...
Event fired...
Event above..

> I suspect indeed that the EventListener bean is registered twice or
>   something. You can enable
>   org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor to
>   trace level to check what happens to this particular class.

–  Stéphane Nicoll

**TRACE**
`org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor`It is happening twice for everything

```
12:02:32,878 DEBUG ntext.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor: 138 - 1 @EventListener methods processed on bean 'mailServiceImpl': [public void com.service.MailServiceImpl.sendMailForSuggestedListing(com.service.events.CreationEvent)]
12:02:32,878 DEBUG ntext.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor: 138 - 1 @EventListener methods processed on bean 'mailServiceImpl': [public void com.service.MailServiceImpl.sendMailForSuggestedListing(com.service.events.CreationEvent)]
12:02:32,878 TRACE ntext.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor: 132 - No @EventListener annotations found on bean class: class com.service.MetaServiceImpl
12:02:32,878 TRACE ntext.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor: 132 - No @EventListener annotations found on bean class: class com.service.MetaServiceImpl
```

> Java configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.**.domain",
        "com.**.repositories", "com.**.service",
        "com.**.security" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ServiceConfig 


Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.**.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.**.config","com.**.rest.controllers","com.**.rest.tokens"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.**.**.repositories")
public class MongoRepositoryConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
```

Comment: somehow is the event listener registered twice? post the class level code for the event listener. what all does it implement?

Comment: @iamiddy - I could not find the `@EventListener` annotation in spring. Could you please let us know from where are you importing this annotation? In a spring application events and listeners are created using `ApplicationEvent` and `ApplicationListener` respectively.

Comment: It could be that your spring context is duplicated e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436195/all-spring-framework-beans-get-duplicated-becase-of-doubled-context-servletco

Comment: I suspect indeed that the EventListener bean is registered twice or something. You can enable `org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor` to trace level to check what happens to this particular class.

Comment: indeed @StéphaneNicoll , by the TRACE as you suggested the EventListener is registered twice, have edited the question to include the trace

Comment: What are `com.service.MailServiceImpl` and `com.idrene.emefana.service.MailServiceImpl`? These are two different classes so this seems logical that you get the event twice. Can you show your config or the code for those classes? Or publish a sample project somewhere.

Comment: `MailServiceImp` l is just another bean in my application and it is the same class. The `EventListenerMethodProcessor` is logging every bean twice, so `MailServiceImpl` is a representation of that, and test-case is firing once . Unless you are implying that `@EventListener` is not to be used in another spring bean, otherwise I don't see why it is logical for this to fire twice

Comment: Well if you have two beans of the same class, then you have two listeners. This seems logical to me. Two beans = two instances = two listeners. I am sorry but it's as far as I can go with the details you give me. Share a project that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: How many config files do you have?
One application-config.xml and another mvc-config.xml and in both you are doing component-scan?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the configurations

Comment: have you solved the question? i'm suffering with same problem.

Comment: I opted to use spring boot instead , and it worked fine.

Comment: @Stéphane Nicoll You can reproduce it by enabling component scanning and manually registering the same Component with a 'Bean' annotation in a configuration class. Although, it seems trivial on the surface I think one can easily stumble up on this issue if they are scanning their entire root package and trouble shooting can be cryptic because there is no warning msg. So I think the 'bug' here is the event listeners with the EXACT same signatures should either override each other or at least a warning msg printed during initialization if the event listener signature was picked up twice...

Comment: I am afraid you have two beans of the same type and we shouldn't prevent anybody to do that if that's what they want. It's a configuration issue; doing what you're proposing is hiding the actual issue.

Comment: @Stéphane Nicoll well i'm saying it shouldn't be an issue... 99/100 use cases are going to desire a single event listener bean with the exact same method signature even if the same eventListener is (accidently) registered twice. I think the issue is if one has a misconfiguration it is not intuitive to trouble shoot and the misconfiguration is hidden. Maybe adding debug or warn log (if possible) in the EventListenerMethodProcessor for possible duplicates would of been helpful

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue. For me... I registered the event listener twice because I blanketed scanned my entire package path in one configuration class

```
@ComponentScan(  basePackages = {"my.root.package"} )
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
      //... 
}
```

and then I manually added the same eventListener bean in another configuration class like so

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
    // SomeEventListener was located @ my.root.package.event and had @Component annotation
    @Bean 
    public SomeEventListener someEventListener() {
        return new SomeEventListener();
    }
    ...
}
```

causing it to register twice.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar situation - events published twice.

Root cause in my case was a misconfiguration of the web application context in `web.xml`: `DispatcherServlet` was passed the same context xml file as was passed to the servlet listener. Replaced the duplicate reference in the `DispatcherServlet` declaration with an empty one, as suggested [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy):

> If an application context hierarchy is not required, applications may configure a “root” context only and leave the contextConfigLocation Servlet parameter empty.

That resolved the issue for me.