# spring correctitud validation

Tags: java, spring

I have been working from a while with spring framework for Java: I work in a continuous integration environment. So I just realized that I make classes and in general application self tested using unit test and integration test. BUT is really commond to get every test ok but the application fail because spring configuration and the only way to get know is running the application.

Run the application sound like a trivial activity but in my case take several minutes (because the complexity) a lot of dependencies resolution. So my questions is. There is any way to validate o test spring configuration without actually run in and get the exception?.

Answer (score 0):

**first**

I develop web based applications and there it is common to have two nested spring contexts: the inner one that contains the Services and Repository and the outer one, that contains the Frontend Controller, as well as the trigger that starts when the application is up ([ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9016122/280244)).

For our tests I have at least on test that fires up the inner spring context. This take even for not so small applications only between 10 and 20 seconds.

So my suggestion for you is: I you cant start the complete application for testing because it takes to long, try to split and start only the one that often cause the problems.

**second**

Use a Continues Integration Server, that test the application after each checkin in your Source Code Repository. If this takes only some minutes for the tests than the feedback for the developer should be immediately enough. This would not mean that the developer is not responsible to check in only code that does not fail the tests, but it create a good safety net if one developer fails.