# What happens when we don't register ContextLoaderListener?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I tried to find some explanation for what really happens when we do not register `ContextLoaderListener` in our `web.xml` file, mainly because I have a simple Spring + Hibernate app that works fine if I DO NOT declare `ContextLoaderListener`. When I do, I get 404 error.

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.myfantasticwebsite"/>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzashop"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>org.myfantasticwebsite</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I also have `index.jsp` that just displays some stuff from database. All 3 files (`web.xml`, `applicationContext.xml` and `index.jsp`) are located in `WEB-INF` directory, and everything works fine until I add `ContextLoaderListener` bean to `web.xml`. After, I get Page not found error on address localhost:8080/pizzashop.

This is just a simple tutorial I found on internet, that's why all configuration is in one file. I was actually trying make separate config files - 2 files stemming from `web.xml` (`dispatcher-servlet.xml` with web related config and `applicationContext.xml` with everything else). Further more to extract hibernate specific config to `hibernate.cfg.xml`, and spring+hibernate config to `hibernate-context.xml`.

Can someone please explain why I get 404 error, I'm stuck here for a week now. Thank you.

This is the only controller - PizzaController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PizzaController {

  @Autowired private PizzaDAO pizzaDAO;

  /**
   * This handler method is invoked when
   * http://localhost:8080/pizzashop is requested.
   * The method returns view name "index"
   * which will be resolved into /WEB-INF/index.jsp.
   *  See src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
   */
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String list(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDAO.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "index";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: web.xml with `ContextLoaderListener`:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not

Comment: I saw that, there's no answer to my question, unfortunately. @TheHeadRush

Comment: Where i come from, there's a saying "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." That being the case, my reply was referring to the part where it said "if the app works, don't worry about it'

Comment: Funny :) But I'm really, really curious, I just need to know stuff. Thanks though.

Comment: WEB-INF is in the right place?

Comment: Do you a server startup error? Can you show your web.xml with the ContextLoaderListener added

Comment: yep, `src>main>webapp>WEB-INF` @TheHeadRush

Comment: I updated my post @6ton I don't get server startup error, just page not found.

Comment: You should have a contextConfigLocation parameter to specify the spring xml. Though I am not sure if the missing parameter results in spring context initialization. Are you getting any error on server startup?

Comment: I tried that, no change. And no error on server startup. @6ton