# How can we create more than one IOC Container in a Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to know how can we create more than one IOC Container in a single project of the Spring ?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context1.xml");
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context2.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two independent IOC Containers just by creating them.

```
ApplicationContext contextA = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:contextA.xml");
ApplicationContext contextB = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:contextB.xml");
```

You can also create two or more IOC Contains that depends in a parent/child relationship (like Spring Core Context and Spring Web Context does ([ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not))) via `AbstractApplicationContext.setParent(ApplicationContext)`

```
ApplicationContext parent =...

AbstractApplicationContext contextA = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:contextA.xml");
contextA.setParent(parent);
AbstractApplicationContext contextB = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:contextB.xml");
contextB.setParent(parent);
```