# what is the difference between xml files Spring and Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I start to learn spring recently.
My goal is to use spring MVC to do restful api
I know spring MVC is web framework in spring
I know that in spring,there is beans.xml
And in spring MVC , there is  servletname-servlet.xml
I want to know where is difference??
Is it means if I use spring MVC,I don't need to use beans.xml??

Please give me some way or give me example project link with spring and spring MVC together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servletname-servlet.xml defines the beans for one servlet's app context. There can be number of servlets in a webapp and for every servlet we have servletname-servlet.xml (e.g. spring1-servlet.xml for servlet1, spring2-servlet.xml for servlet2).

Beans defined in servletname-servlet.xml can reference beans in beans.xml, but not vice versa.

All Spring MVC controllers must go in the servletname-servlet.xml context.

Beans.xml contain beans that are shared between all servlets in a webapp.Usually the beans.xml context is not necessary if you have only one servlet in your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You could define all your beans in **servletname-servlet.xml** but it's not a good practice.

Usually if you create a web application in 'pure' spring (ie. without spring MVC) then you will add ContextLoaderListener as a filter to your **web.xml**. Then spring will look for **applicationContext.xml** when you will usually import **beans.xml**.

In **servletname-servlet.xml** you define servlets. Servlets can refer other beans. So it's good practice to separate front (servlets) from backend (beans.xml).

Also remember that beans declared in **servletname-servlet.xml** are [overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

See also better answer at: [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not)