# Which instance in Spring MVC framework is created first?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to `spring MVC`. Can anyone please tell me which instance is created first in `Spring MVC framework`? This question was asked in interview.

I answered `Dispatcher Servlet` but that was not correct answer as per interviewer.

Can anyone please explain instance creation sequences in `spring MVC framework`?

Comment: instance of what? That question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I think he talks about spring contexts

Answer (score 0):

I would call it an **spring-context** but not an "instance". Anyway: In a typical spring web application you have two spring-contexts:

- the one that is created by the `ContextLoaderListener`, and
- the one that is created by the `DispatcherServlet`

The one created by the `ContextLoaderListener` is created first and become the parent context of the one create by the `DispatcherServlet`.

@See: [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9016122/280244) for some more insights.