# Resource not found(404) when adding ContextLoaderListener and RequestContextListener in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

when I am adding `ContextLoaderListener` to my `web.xml` then got the message of resource not found(404). when I am remove the listener class from `web.xml` then my `index.php` running but adding

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

- this two lines give me the resource not found error **eclipse kepler** version.When I am adding these two lines in `web.xml` and prepare the code as it was then heading this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

I am tried hard and I am new to spring framework. Can you tell me is anything setup needed for listener or anything else?

Error in Console:

```
                               *

Jan 27, 2016 12:47:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@1cefe08] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 or below with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
```

*

Web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FutureKid</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>InputFormServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>InputFormServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.webapp.InputFormServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InputFormServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/input-form</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>CustomerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.webapp.CustomerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/get-customer</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: ContextLoaderListener for a php application?

Comment: can you provide whole web.xml?

Comment: Jens: It's pure java application. Basically web dynamic project in eclipse kepler version.

Comment: Yadvendra: I am posting the whole web.xml ASAP

Comment: Where is your Spring DispatcherServlet? and what is your "com.webapp.InputFormServlet" -- this defently looks not like a Spring MVC Standard configuration. Of course you can do so if you have a good reason, but then you should know how Spring works. If not keep on using the Spring Standard way, with ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet, but without other Servlets. (this tutorial looks good: http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/8108/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: Thank you Ralph. Yes I am new in Spring and it's my mistake that I tagged it with spring-mvc. It's a simple spring web app and I have solved it by putting xerces jar in my containing ext folder of run time. Also you can do by adding xerces in your maven dependencies. Thanks for your tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the `ContextLoaderListener` is not enougth, you also need to configure the beans that are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.  Tyicaly you configure the name of an spring xml file for the `ContextLoaderListener` (via context-param `contextConfigLocation`) and then add some spring configuration to this file.

You also should read ["ContextLoaderListener or not?" question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not), it will give you some brife understanding of the two spring contexts.  It also contains some example configuration of the `web.xml`

Comment: I am using applicationContext.xml where the beans are placed. So I think there is no need of spring.xml. I have also provide the address using RequestDispatcher for jsps.  Is there also need of spring.xml?

Comment: **Solved !!!**    It's solved by using xerces jar in my run time ext folder. Actually it's a XSD parser exception that's why I got resources not available message. Also you can solve it by adding  xerces jars in maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First add the following to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Next create a spring.xml in WEB-INF/spring folder and change it as required.

Example spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
     <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I am using applicationContext.xml where the beans are placed. So I think there is no need of spring.xml. I have also provide the address using RequestDispatcher for jsps.  Is there also need of spring.xml?