# Spring Security CustomUserDetailsService - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement a CustomUserDetailsService for Spring security. I did the same successfully in a different project, but now i keep either getting a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' is defined`.
Or an Instantiation Exception for springSecurityFilterChain.
My conclusion is, that something is horribly wrong with my configuration.

So here are my files:

web.xml

```
     <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">



<display-name>MVC</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When this is included instead of security.xml in the init-param tag, i get the InstantiationException for the springSecurityFilterChain (project starts though)

```
  <!--   <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
               /WEB-INF/security.xml         
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
 -->
```

2nd part of web.xml

```
   <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>
   <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            </filter>

            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>


            <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

               <!-- Welcome page -->                    
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <!-- JSF mapping -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>



    </web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Componenten Scannen -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="QUEST.l01.Controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="QUEST.l01.Model" />
     <context:component-scan base-package="QUEST.l01.Services" />


     <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quest_l01" />
        <property name="username" value="l01" />
        <property name="password" value="SqXrCty9xUR47PwS" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="QUEST.l01.Model" />   
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>              
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="QUEST.l01.Model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <!-- <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

     <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/> -->


    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- Maximum file size: 1MB -->
        <!-- 1MB = 125000 Byte -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />

    </bean>



    <jpa:repositories base-package="QUEST.l01.Model"/>



</beans>
```

security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

         <!-- unsecured pathes (for web ressources like js, img, css -->
    <http pattern="/resources" security="none" />

        <!-- secured pathes -->
    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>


        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login/failure" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>

        <logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/login" 
            logout-url="/logout"/>
    </http>

        <beans:bean id="AuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="QUEST.l01.Services.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

First lines of CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
```

I would be grateful for any solutions/hints. What am i understanding wrong?

Comment: well, InstantiationException happens when you put security.xml beans into Root Application Context. and as Dispatcher's web Application Context is not available to Root, it can't find bean see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not.

Comment: another thing is about declaration. it seems that component scan some how miss the bean declaration. it might be a wrong path or similar. you could try to move declaration from java to xml, for testing and see whether that would work

Comment: Ok so what i understand from the post you linked me, is that i have to put the security.xml out of the servlet context.  So i did that, but i still get the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for my `customUserDetailsService"

Comment: customUserDetailsService should be visible to authenticationManager. it means that either they both should be in the same container or customUserDetailsService should be in Root, if authenticationManager would be in web AC

Comment: in which package `CustomUserDetailsService` exists ?

Comment: AuthenticationManager is defined in the security.xml, which is loaded via Listener, so it is not in the same Context as the applicationContext.xml(missleading name) in the servlet. But the component scan is done in the applicationContext.xml, so the Service might not be visible to the AuthenticationManager. Is that about right?

The Service is in package QUEST.l01.Model.usermanagement

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your class CustomUserDetailsService is available for scanning. Spring will scan all the beans available in base-package.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourapplication" />
```

The base package configuration is typically in application-context.xml or in another configuration file. Configure the base package if not already done. Also make sure you have enabled annotations using the following code.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

It will declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers e.g. @RequestBody.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The package is in QUEST.l01.Model.usermanagement , which is available for scanning. My theory is, that it's been scanned in the wrong context. I defined the Service bean explicitly like `<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="{path}"/>` . The problem seems solved but i can't tell for sure bc i am getting a different arrow, which might not be related to spring security.