# HTTP Status 500 - No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-security

My `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/security-context.xml WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>20848820</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/auditorium</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/booking</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ticket</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/event</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user_pdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my_dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user_upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My `security-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <security:http auto-config="true" name="springSecurityFilterChain" >
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/user/welcome.html"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <security:user password="password" name="username" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

            </security:user-service>

        </security:authentication-provider>

    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

I am trying to solve this problem for a long time an have read a lot about it but hit it anyway. Could you please help me find out what I have omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

See [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the name="springSecurityFilterchain" from your xml configuration:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" name="springSecurityFilterChain" >
```

Just let it like this:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">
```

And If I were you I would map the springSecurityFilterChain filter-mappingn to "/*" :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This way every request will pass through the SpringSecurityFilterChain, and then you could handle every request pattern in your security context.

**EDIT**

Could you try like this:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help