# What is Spring Event propagation?, where it is used in real application? one use case?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

ApplicationContext is supporting event propagation what it means where it is used in our applications, can you please provide any one usecase on this?

Is it sending event from on context to another context or is there any other use?

Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it sending event from one context to another context or is there any other use?

No, the events are only within the context they are fired.

> Spring’s eventing mechanism is designed for simple communication between Spring beans within the same application context. However, for more sophisticated enterprise integration needs, the separately-maintained Spring Integration project provides complete support for building lightweight, pattern-oriented, event-driven architectures that build upon the well-known Spring programming model.
>   (Spring Reference)

Maybe this helps: [How to bridge Spring Application Context events to an other context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534222/how-to-bridge-spring-application-context-events-to-an-other-context)